# Al ejecutar en mi cmd: expo install react-native-maps, aparece "Could not resolve dependency"

Tags: google-maps, react-native, npm, cmd, expo

estoy intentando instalar esto: `expo install react-native-maps`
Pero cuando lo ejecuto me sale este error.
Ya intenté borrar *node_modules* y volver a instalar, pero el error persiste.
Es un proyecto de React Native.

```
C:\Users\ASUS TUFF\Documents\Study\maps-react-native\react-native-maps>expo install react-native-maps
Installing 1 SDK 42.0.0 compatible native module using npm.
> npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: undefined@undefined
npm ERR! Found: react-native-web@0.13.18
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-web
npm ERR!   react-native-web@"~0.13.12" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react-native-web@"^0.11" from react-native-maps@0.28.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-maps
npm ERR!   react-native-maps@"0.28.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\ASUS TUFF\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ASUS TUFF\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-07-29T20_29_51_765Z-debug.log

npm exited with non-zero code: 1
Error: npm exited with non-zero code: 1
    at ChildProcess.completionListener (C:\Users\ASUS TUFF\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\src\spawnAsync.ts:65:13)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\ASUS TUFF\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
    ...
    at Object.spawnAsync [as default] (C:\Users\ASUS TUFF\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\src\spawnAsync.ts:26:19)
    at NpmPackageManager._runAsync (C:\Users\ASUS TUFF\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\package-manager\src\NodePackageManagers.ts:166:31)
    at NpmPackageManager.addAsync (C:\Users\ASUS TUFF\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\package-manager\src\NodePackageManagers.ts:105:18)
    at actionAsync (C:\Users\ASUS TUFF\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\installAsync.ts:122:3)

C:\Users\ASUS TUFF\Documents\Study\maps-react-native\react-native-maps>
```

Comment: Clave: ¿cuáles versiones de `npm`, `react` y `react-native` tenés instaladas?

Comment: Me sale el mismo error. ¿Has encontrado la solución?

Comment: Aqui muestran una posible solucion https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/3865